De-serialize JSON string into .NET object
I have a JSON string something like below:
[
  {
    "movie title": "The Matrix",
    "release date": "1999-03-31",
    "movie rating": 8.7,
    "main actor": {
      "name": "Keanu Reeves",
      "age": 57,
      "gender": "Male"
    },
    "seen": true
  },
  {
    "movie title": "Inception",
    "release date": "2010-07-16",
    "movie rating": 8.8,
    "main actor": {
      "name": "Leonardo DiCaprio",
      "age": 47,
      "gender": "Male"
    },
    "seen": false
  }
]

I need to convert the above JSON string into .NET object type.
Note:
The JSON names cannot be changed as it is coming from an excel document using a webapi call, converting excel data into JSON type.
I'm getting conversion error when converting above JSON string to .NET object.
Please help me fix above issue? Thanks in advance.

What conversion error? Into what types?

There are 2 custom class rquired as below.
Parent class Root that contains the MainActor class
public class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("movie title")]
    public string movietitle { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("release date")]
    public string releasedate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("movie rating")]
    public double movierating { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("main actor")]
    public MainActor mainactor { get; set; }
    public bool seen { get; set; }
}


public class MainActor
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
}

Now, to create c# object from json string. Do this below.
    var jsonSting = @"[
 {
 "movie title": "The Matrix",
 "release date": "1999-03-31",
 "movie rating": 8.7,
 "main actor": {
  "name": "Keanu Reeves",
  "age": 57,
  "gender": "Male"
 },
 "seen": true
},
{
"movie title": "Inception",
"release date": "2010-07-16",
"movie rating": 8.8,
"main actor": {
  "name": "Leonardo DiCaprio",
  "age": 47,
  "gender": "Male"
},
"seen": false
}
]";
var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Root>>(jsonString); 

myObject the expected .NET object
Though the code is not tested yet should work.

Thanks Ajeet, now I could able to see the object populates with proper values. But stuck with another issue while passing the object (as a DataTable) to the backend sproc input param is table-parameter. It is actually passing the class name and all other fields as NULLs inside the table.  any idea how to fix that? Thanks once again.

Below the sample code: code
Here personTable is DataTable object:
personTable.Rows.Add(person);
using (SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
{
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "dbo.usp_AddPerson";
SqlParameter personParam = new SqlParameter();

personParam.ParameterName = "@Person";
personParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
personParam.Value = personTable;

cmd.Parameters.Add(personParam);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

};`code'

check this link pass-datatable-to-sproc
